2019: a year in moderation
It's New Year's Day in Stack Exchange land...
A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
  -- A Theory of Moderation

While there certainly are Moderators here, a significant amount of the moderation is done by ordinary people, using the privileges 
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.
As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together. 
And what could be more festive than a big pile of numbers? 
So here is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Cryptography over the past 12 months:
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                   4         14
Users destroyed³                                   9          0
Users deleted                                      5          0
Users contacted                                   14          0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue            199      1,563
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue                52        192
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue          16        182
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue                14        197
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue                 62      2,353
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue               490      1,866
Tags merged                                        6          0
Tag synonyms proposed                              3          0
Tag synonyms created                               3          0
Questions unprotected                              1          0
Questions reopened                                54          0
Questions protected                                7         11
Questions migrated                               190          0
Questions merged                                   7          0
Questions flagged⁵                                13        587
Questions closed                               1,181        201
Question flags handled⁵                          331        267
Posts unlocked                                     0         34
Posts undeleted                                    7         99
Posts locked                                       5        233
Posts deleted⁶                                   266      2,132
Posts bumped                                       0        435
Escalations to the Community Manager team          3          0
Comments undeleted                                18          0
Comments flagged                                  24        850
Comments deleted⁷                              1,680      3,219
Comment flags handled                            164        710
Bounties canceled                                  1          0
Answers flagged                                   33        444
Answer flags handled                             425         52
All comments on a post moved to chat              38          0

Footnotes
¹ "Community" here refers both to the membership of Cryptography without diamonds next to their names, and to the automated systems otherwise known as user #-1.
² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.
³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.
⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.
⁵ Includes close flags (but not close or reopen votes).
⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.
⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).   
Further reading:

Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? I posted a similar report here last year: 2018: a year in moderation...
You can also check out this report on other sites
Or peruse detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Footnote: I often help close questions after they have a significant amount of close votes obtained already. Basically I'm then acting as some kind of user with extreme closing powers (mods cannot cast a single close vote, unfortunately). That may significantly skew the statistics towards the "moderators closing the question", so that statistic should be taken with a huge grain of salt - you guys are indicating which questions should be closed, not us mods.

I should've really clarified this in footnotes, but ... When there are other close votes besides the moderators' on a question, it counts in the "community" column, @maarten

That cannot be right? Questions closed (mods) 1,181 (community) 201 - I'm pretty sure that the mods didn't close that many questions without the community casting at least one close vote. OT: very glad you're still around, Shog9 - thanks for taking the time!

Yeah... Sadly, I can't double-check my work on the actual numbers anymore. If you wanna do a sanity check yourself, get a random sample of closed questions (from search closed:1 deleted:all) and check votes from the timeline.

I was kind of afraid of that answer when I posted the comment. Will possibly try and do check upon the stats. But I'm not Anglo-saxon, so I'm not that much into stats anyway - this one just stood out, and I was afraid it communicated the wrong idea. Especially since it was topic of discussion. So yeah, grain of salt...

Oh, I guess we have done something then :)
Thanks to all the users helping to keep the site in shape.
A special thanks to all the dupe hunters out there, that can be hard work and your searching capabilities are highly appreciated.
I hope you all can spare some time to keep the site clean in 2020. A very happy new year to anybody reading this message!
